# create static button at the end of footer in android

Tags: android

i want to create button at the end of ListView means at the Footer that remain with the View  but when listview scrolls down it must remain static at te end of view in android. look at my code
  [Here](http://pastebin.com/Xufq0GTN)

Comment: Have you tried enclosing a ListView and a Button inside a Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the List view using the two layout one is using for the button and other is using  the  Listview.this is the solution for button remain static.

```
    <RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      >
    <Button 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
      />    
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     </ListView>
```

Comment: i tried it already when i drag listview it is invisible andwhen i reied to layout_width="fill_parent" it is not showing properly

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout to enclose your Listview and your button. In button use attribute alignParentBottom=true...

Comment: i want button to be a static on a View

Comment: IN the layout by Nitesh ... enclose your listview and button inside relative layout. make layout_height for listview as wrap_content instead of fill_parent.